# Set ClientName to OPC Server

Tags: opc

I implemented a client for OPC DA version 2.05, used the OPC Foundation library. I need to tell the OPC server the name of the client. But I can't find the right method or property of the Server object. I'm doing something wrong maybe?
For example, so is done in another library TitaniumAS.Opc

```
server.Connect();
if (server.IsConnected)
  server.ClientName = "MyClient";
```

Perhaps there is a easy decision to the problem, but I don't see it...

Comment: Have you tried setting the ClientName before connection?

Comment: I didn't find the ClientName property! I had to use TitaniumAS.OPC